# 432 4.3.2 STOREDRV.ClientSubmit; sender thread limit exceeded?

Tags: excel, email, office365, nodemailer

I tried to upload an excel sheet which contains 1000 user records. I tried to send a temporary password to these users, in some cases it succeedded and in other cases i I got the error `432 4.3.2 STOREDRV.ClientSubmit;` sender thread limit exceeded.
Can you please help how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow, can you provide a bit more details about your problem and also show us your code or what  you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi I tried to onboard 1000 user via excel in this time every user send password via mail but some user got mail , but  some user not sending mail I got exception for "432 4.3.2 STOREDRV.ClientSubmit; sender thread limit exceeded"

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport((smtpTransport({
    service: 'Office365',
    host: 'smtp.office365.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    requireTLS: true,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.NODEMAILER_EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.NODEMAILER_PASSWORD
    }
})));
 this my code can you pls help me @StephanHogenboom

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/issue-while-sending-email-using-nodemailer/81a02184-ba14-4587-bee7-3204e7d4f539 @StephanHogenboom can you see this document how to solve this problem please help me on this

Answer (score 11):

there is a limit of up to three concurrent connections for Office365, as stated in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/send-emails/smtp-submission-improvements):

> New throttling limit for concurrent connections that submit messages
>
> The service has various limits to prevent abuse and to ensure fair use. An additional limit is being added. **Under the new limit, up to three concurrent connections are allowed** to send email messages at the same time. If an application tries to send more than three messages at the same time by using multiple connections, each connection will receive the following error message:
>
> **432 4.3.2 STOREDRV.ClientSubmit; sender thread limit exceeded**

Please observe that there are other limits too.

To solve the problem you can:

- Try to send the emails in sequence and give a little bit of time between every item
- Try to use a service that is made for sending a large number of messages, because clearly Office365 is imposing limits to use the service only as a user, not in an automated service.

Comment: Adding 1s between each call, as suggested, solved this problem to my case. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me. Delay execution by 1 sec between calls. Add this line TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); between two calls.